# Sorting in gridview is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, ado.net

I am trying Sorting functionality in Grid view but its not working.Can some body help?

Code:

```
  private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
            break;

        case SortDirection.Descending:
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
            break;
    }

    return newSortDirection;
}
protected DataSet FillDataSet()
{
    string source = "Database=GridTest;Server=Localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes";
    con = new SqlConnection(source);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_mygrid", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    return ds;


}
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    if (dt != null)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
   }
```

Here dt is coming null.why? pls help thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
enter code here  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="12" 
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
```

**EDIT(Total code)**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                break;

            case SortDirection.Descending:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }
    protected DataSet FillDataSet()
    {
        string source = "Database=GridTest;Server=Localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes";
        con = new SqlConnection(source);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_mygrid", con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        return ds;


    }
    protected void GetValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillDataSet();
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
       int newPagenumber = e.NewPageIndex;
       GridView1.PageIndex = newPagenumber;
       GridView1.DataSource = FillDataSet();
       GridView1.DataBind();

    }


    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = FillDataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (dt != null)
        {
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CODE:

```
private string GetSortDirection(string column)
{
       string sortDirection = "DESC";
       string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

       if (sortExpression != null)
       {    
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "DESC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "ASC";
                }
            }
       }

       ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
       ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

       return sortDirection;
}

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = ((DataSet)Session["myDataSet"]).Tables[0];
   dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation both to the problem and to your code please? Your code might seem obvious to some but also might not be like for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting a `DataSet` as `DataSource` and then casting it to `DataTable` with the operator [`as`](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2008/08/net-difference-between-casting-and-as.html).

The 'as' operator in C# is a tentative cast - if it's impossible to cast (types are not compatible) instead of throwing an exception as the direct cast the 'as' operator sets the reference to null.

If you only have one datatable in your dataset then you can get the first element like this:

```
ds.Tables[0];
```

... or use the name of the table:

```
ds.Tables["myTable"];
```

in your case you can try...

```
DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource.Tables[0] as DataTable;
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**:

with regards to your sorting problem (once you get the datatable):

```
if (dt != null) 
{ 
   dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection); 
   GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

You can do this because dt is a reference to the exact same object that's already set as DataSource for your grid. It should do the trick - if not there's smt else I am missing (such as we're sorting the wrong table meaning you have more than one table in the DataSet).

**EDIT:**

had a look at your code. I don't know exactly when GetValues gets fired but I suspect it's causing your problem (I think it might be overriding your sorting or smt along those lines).

If you comment out FillDataSource from getValues and modify your PageLoad to do this:

```
  void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 

     // Load data only once, when the page is first loaded.
     if (!IsPostBack)
     { 
        Session["myDataSet"] = FillDataSet();
     }

  }
```

then in your sort method you retrieve the DataSource like this:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataSet)Session["myDataSet"]).Tables[0];
```

Also you can retrieve the DataSet from session in your pagination handler method.

You should also notice an improvement in performance since you're retrieving the stuff form the db just once.

Give it a shot!

Comment: Tried and changed the code to  DataSet ds = FillDataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (dt != null)
        {......}
Now dv.Sort is having value "Id ASc"[Id name of a col]..but still the sorting is not working :-(

Comment: for the sorting this will work: 

myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "myColumnOfChoice DESC";

you need to sort the default view of your datatable.

Comment: just go: dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ID ASC";

Comment: Not working..updated code:

  DataSet ds = FillDataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
      

        if (dt != null)
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
            //dv.Sort = e.SortExpression +" "+ ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
            GridView1.DataSource = dv;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        
        
        }
any clue?

Comment: yes instead of creating a new DataView (dv) just go: dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ID ASC"; as in my previous comment and then just call GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: you don't need to reassign the datasource you just need to sort the default view of the current datasource (in your case the datatable dt)

Comment: Getting a bit confused..can u pls code it.
Do un want some thing like:
 if (dt != null)
        {
            
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
            
           
            GridView1.DataBind();
        
        
        }

Comment: Thanks for all ur help but it didnt work :-(. No I have only one table.also edited the post for Gridview? pls look at it..Am I missing something there?

Comment: try resetting dt as datasource right before GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: already tried but didnt work..here are some findings, I have 3 cols..Id,Fname and Lname.when i click on Id nothing happens but when I click on Fname the first(only first) row gets sorted.rest of teh rows doesnt change..

Comment: are you databinding somewhere else? maybe you are overriding the sorting. Is FillDataSet called every pageload or where?

Comment: FillDataSet is a separate method for filling the dataset.code is already there in original post.I am calling this method from Sorting method.For every sorting this will b called.

Comment: yes - but the sorting causes triggers a postback causing the whole page to reload. I'd say put breakpoints in your code every time you do a DataBind() on the grid and see if the one in the sorting method is the last one to fire. If not that's the reason why it doesn't work. If it's the last then again we're missing smt else :)

Comment: can you please show your pageLoad? are you doing something like this in it? if (!IsPostBack){ FillDataSet();}

Comment: have a look at this link - code is pretty similar except that he's storing the dataview in session and using it as datasource --> http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/sortingaspgrid.html . As an alternative - this guy is reloading the data when he needs to sort (which I do not advice but it's another alternative) --> http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=53 .

Comment: Finally its working. I have updated the code.Thaks a lot for all ur help..It was really a long Comment chain.  :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Testing.aspx.cs

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataset != null)
    {
        datatable = dataset.Tables[0];
        DataView dataView = new DataView(datatable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression;
        GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

In Testing.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
```